# Flipping between two UIView inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, flip

I have a scrollview with lots of subviews, my problem is when i tap one of the subviews i want to change it to some other view that i would create in that moment.

Imagine this case: having a picture gallery and when you tap on one pic it would show the backside of the photo (having some kind of info about it).

At the moment, i know which one i've taped onto and fliping it is also OK, but setting this new UIView in its place with the flipping animation... i'm not getting it!

Thx in advance for your time.

EDIT:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:recognizer.view toView:flyerInfoView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I've made this, but i'm having 2 problems, i can't back to my other view (as i've read in the documentation this method removes the "fromView" from the superscreen) and the other one is... It is fliping all my views not the only one i'm touching.

You can see that fromView is recognizer.view, i'll briefly explain, i have a UIGestureRecognizer assign to each view so i can understand which view is being touched. The method that is fliping the view is: handleTapFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer

how this can give you a more detailed info about my problem.
Again thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to use UIView's method `transitionFromView:toView:...`? There are some Flip options too.

Comment: Yes! Im using that method now.Once i've get home i'll post the code i'm using.
At the moment i change view but can't get the fliping animation. it instantly changes to the new view without the animation.

Comment: [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView transitionFromView:recognizer.view toView:flyerInfoView duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
[UIView commitAnimations];


With this, it transits to next view however i doesn't to the fliping annotation.